# Safe Area insetsLayoutMargins not work as I expect

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9-beta, safearealayoutguide

I'm trying to use the new safe area.
I'm trying to reproduce the example that is shown WWDC 2017 - Session 204.

[image]

I set `additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake (0, 0, 44, 100)` of the controller and `insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false` of the red color containing textfield, but I did not have the result I expected the text field is ignored from safe area using margins to be relative to the view's bounds.

Comment: share storyboard layout and constraints view here

Comment: @Krunal This is my [storyboard](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fgznFvBkidenRjZmdKZXJVUnM/view?usp=sharing)